# angular, node + Service that returns SQL Data as json

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angularjs

Total newbee here. Given this service.js how can I go about returning terms data from sql server

```
    app.service('termsService', function () {
    this.getTerms = function () {
        return terms 
    };

    var terms = [

            {
                termid: 11, term: 'Shanika', termDefinition: 'Passmore'
            }
        ];

});
```

The code below works well on its own so I want to return terms data in the service call above

```
    var sql = require('msnodesql')
    , nconf = require('nconf')
    ,express = require('express');

nconf.env()
     .file({ file: 'config.json' });

var connectionString = nconf.get("SQL_CONN"); 
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    sql.open(connectionString, function(err, conn) {
        if(err) {
        }
        else {
            conn.queryRaw("SELECT TOP 10 termid, term, termDefinition FROM Terms", function(err, results) {
                if(err) {
                }
                else {
                    res.json(results);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A code for your angular service :

```
function Service($http) {
    var Service = {};

    Service.getCriteria = function (criteria,callback) {

        $http({
            url: "YOUR URL",
            params: criteria,
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }).success(callback)
    }

    return Service;
}
```

Be aware of that is an async call, so use promises, callback or sync methods.

Comment: ok took a little while to wrap my head around this but I got it working. Thank Skahrz